# Data race within Go function with named return values?

Tags: go

## Question

Is there a non-obvious data race within the following code between `qux()` writing to the `err` at the same time when a new error `baz` is being returned? Is it possible that Go internal handling of the [named return values](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results) treats explicit returning of a new variable as a de facto assignment to the named return value and thus allowing a data race here?

```golang
func foo(baz time.Duration) (bar *Bar, err error) {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    
    go func() {
        bar, err = qux()
        close(done)
    }()

    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case <-time.After(baz):
        return nil, errors.New("baz")
    }
}
```

This does not make any sense for me, as I would expect that result of `errors.New()` in the above code should be allocated to a different address than the pre-initialized `err`. However, I have reasons to suspect that this is exactly what happened to me.

## Background

One of our services is executing a bit less than a half of a million HTTP requests per second over multiple pods in a cluster. Averagely once per 500 million or so requests we got an irrecoverable fault panic happening during checking of a wrapped error [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/d83168eb385f7ae38710028fff5c84252267adbc/src/errors/wrap.go#L49) in the standard library. It happens usually when a non-nil pointer points to a faulty memory address, which suggests concurrent writes.

```
unexpected fault address 0x0
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x80 addr=0x0 pc=0x40ebfa]

goroutine 7431988 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x1bcf57c, 0x5)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x72 fp=0xc0026e8d38 sp=0xc0026e8d08 pc=0x43bef2
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:727 +0x405 fp=0xc0026e8d68 sp=0xc0026e8d38 pc=0x452805
runtime.getitab(0x195cae0, 0xe93824548b483024, 0x1, 0x7f7fc8037af8)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/iface.go:39 +0x3a fp=0xc0026e8db8 sp=0xc0026e8d68 pc=0x40ebfa
runtime.assertI2I2(0x195cae0, 0xdcd388, 0x0, 0x7f7fc8037af8, 0xc018808a20, 0xc012bbaa01)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/iface.go:472 +0x6a fp=0xc0026e8de8 sp=0xc0026e8db8 pc=0x41004a
errors.Is(0x1dd3f20, 0xc0120b6780, 0x1dd2a60, 0xc00003c1c0, 0xc019510c60)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/wrap.go:49 +0xd8 fp=0xc0026e8e50 sp=0xc0026e8de8 pc=0xaacbf8
```

The code we run looks more or less like this:

```golang
func (c *client) Get(ctx context.Context, query Query) (Results, error) {
    b, err := c.fetchAndLearn(ctx, query)
    if errors.Is(err, context.Canceled) { // Panic happens on this line
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

func (c *client) fetchAndLearn(ctx context.Context, query Query) (response *http.Response, err error) {
    done := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        response, err = c.fetch(ctx, query)
        close(done)
    }()

    select {
    case <-done:
        return
    case <-clock.After(c.getTimeout(query)):
        return nil, xerrors.New("timeout exceeded")
    }
}
```

After fruitless debugging I wondered if Go was doing something unintuitive under the hood due to the fact that named return values were used here. Having this faint intuition I fixed our issue with irrecoverable panics simply by removing named return values and declaring separate err variables.

```golang
func (c *client) fetchAndLearn(ctx context.Context, query Query) (*http.Response, error) {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    var response *http.Response
    var err error

    go func() {
        response, err = c.fetch(ctx, query)
        close(done)
    }()

    select {
    case <-done:
        if err != nil {
            return nil, xerrors.Errorf(": %w", err)
        }
        return response, nil
    case <-clock.After(c.getTimeout(query)):
        return nil, xerrors.New("timeout exceeded during request duration learning")
    }
}
```

But it still does not make that much sense for me and I would really appreciate if someone with a good understanding of Go inner workings either confirm or deny my suspicion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "time race vulnerability", but it does appear you have a data race. Have you tested this with the race detector? That would be more helpful, as it should point out the conflicting reads and writes to the value.

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by "named parameters", or what bearing that would have on a data race. Can you clarify the question? And, as Jim suggests, run with the race detector?

Comment: I think "named return values" is what you're trying to say, not "named parameters".

Comment: Thank you for input. Just let me clarify that named return values are called exactly as __named return parameters__ by the Go own [documentation](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results) and data race/time race are often used interchangeably, nonetheless I'll edit the question to be less confusing. Running a data race detector was the first thing I did when I was debugging this, but it did not detect the race in `fetchAndLearn`. The entire question is not about what happened but why. I'll now edit the question to be easier to understand without mind leaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

Yes, explicit return in a named return function is written to preinitialized named results as per [documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements).

## Background

If you run following code you will notice that even though in `foo()` the preinitialized `val` is never manipulated directly after initial assignment it changes contents after `val2` is returned.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    val := foo()
    fmt.Printf("Main: %+v\n", val.Bar) // explicit
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}

type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}

func foo() (val *Foo) {
    val = &Foo{Bar: "named"}
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("Goroutine: %+v\n", val.Bar) // explicit
    }()

    val2 := &Foo{Bar: "explicit"}

    return val2
}
```

This happens because in Go a zero-valued return parameters are initialized on each function start. Then upon return any returned values are assigned to the preinitialized ones. In our example upon return `val2` is assigned to `val`, which then is returned by the function. This opens the possibility of a data race, because even if you are assigning value to a `val2` it will eventually be assigned to the `val` too.

My only excuse is that as of the time of writing this the official [effective Go guide](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results) is slightly unintuitive as it says that *named results are initialized and tied to an unadorned return* which falsely presupposes that an **explicit return is not tied**. Credit goes to helpful guys behind [go101](https://github.com/go101).